# References to Lie algebras representaions

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Could you give me a reference to a brief introduction to representations of Lie algebras, especially $\mathrm{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$. I mean some basic Verma modules, Weyl groups etc.

Comment: I suggest this [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Lectures-SL2--Modules-Voldymyr-Mazorchuk/dp/184816517X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1400931694&sr=8-1&keywords=lectures+on+sl2)

Comment: [Introduction to Lie Groups and Lie Algebras](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~kirillov/mat552/liegroups.pdf) by A. Kirillov, Jr

Comment: [The one I learned this stuff from.](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algebras-Representation-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387900535)